# Recommendations for a charting software

Tags: jquery, charts

i want to draw organization charts from database records.

I want to overlay nodes if they meet certain criteria. while there are many software which could draw an organization charts, i need one which can allow for overlapping nodes.

i have tried to use jqChart but it cannot overlap nodes.

any recommendations?

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on what you mean by "overlapping nodes"?

Comment: http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/

Comment: by overlapping i mean that suppose if person A is out sick and person B offers to cover for her then node for person B should be placed on top-offset of node A and person B may not even belong to the set of connected nodes

Answer (score 1):

[D3.js](http://d3js.org/) can totally do this. The "downside" to it being that it can do a lot, which is why the learning curve is a bit steep. Just check out the [examples](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery). I was using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) for a while, which offers some neat *Canvas* charts, but it's really basic. So, when we needed more custom behaviour, I switched to D3. If you like it, just look up a bar chart tutorial to get you started and see how far it takes you.

Oh, and it's not based on jQuery, it has its own selectors but you might be able to use jQuery selectors as well.

Comment: D3 looks great but it's huge. worth considering. will wait for some more feedback.